# Password fields are cleared when popup is closed

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I have few password fields and a dropdown box.  Whenever  drop down value is changed (value change event), I am displaying a popup to agree to Terms&Conditions.  As soon as Terms&Conditions are accepted, password fields are cleared.

XHTML file

```
Enter Password: <h:inputSecret value="#{myBean.password}" />
Confirm Password: <h:inputSecret value="#{myBean.confirmPassword}" />
Select an Amount: <h:selectOneMenu value="#{myBean.amount}">
  <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.amountValues}" />
  <f:ajax event="valueChange" render="@this">
    <rich:componentControl target="pnl" operation="show" />
  </f:ajax>
</h:selectOneMenu>
<rich:popupPanel id="pnl" domElementAttachment="form" height="150" width="400" moveable="false" resizeable="false">
  <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Do you accept our Terms&Conditions"/></f:facet>
  <h:commandButton value="Yes" immediate="true" action="#{myBean.agreed}"/>
  <h:commandButton value="No" immediate="true" action="#{myBean.disagreed}" />
</rich:popupPanle>
```

MyBean

```
public void agreed() {
  //set some variables
}
public void disagreed() {
  //set some variables
}
```

For some reason whole page is getting rendered, since the form is not submitted yet, the password values are not set in the bean.  How can I prevent it?

Comment: The code is bahaving exactly as you programmed it to do. The `<h:commandButton>` doesn't perform an ajax submit or so. It just performs a full synchronous submit with a full page reload. Perhaps you missed that fact somehow? Or, if that's *actually* your intent, what's the `immediate="true"` then doing there?

Comment: Replacing `<h:commandButton>` with `<a4j:commandButton>` fixed the issue, but now once after the popup is closed, it is clearing all `<rich:message>` on the page.